# How to replace a portion of a std string with its own substring

Tags: c++11, std

I am a beginner in C++. Consider the following definition for a C++ string

```
std::string str(10, 0); // str needs to be fixed size throughout its lifetime
str = "abcdefgh";  // could be underfilled
```

Let the length of the string be n. I need to move the last k characters ( < n) to the head of the string. I don't care about the contents after this k substring once I move it to the head. But, I want the size of my string to remain fixed and want to perform this without having to allocate any temporary strings.

std::string:replace() could help me do this, but is it safe to pass str as the string argument to str.replace()?

Another option is to do something like this

```
str = str.substr(/* last k chars */) + str.substr(/* don't care */)
```

Does this line update str in-place? If so, does it still maintain the length that I had constructed it with?

Comment: `str.substr()` will create a new string, then it will use `operator+` to concatenate it with second substring. After that it will replace str contents.

Comment: `std::copy(str.begin() + (n-k), str.end(), str.begin());`